# Visual Studio debugger fails during mixed code debugging

Tags: .net, debugging, c++-cli, native, mixed-mode

I have c# gui application, which uses C++/Cli binding library (it uses two native c++ libraries). My application works fine. But during debugging function of c++/cli library my debugger (MSVC2013) fails with such message:

> The Common Language Runtime cannot stop at this exception. Common causes include: incorrect COM interop marshalling, and memory corruption. To investigate further, using native-only debugging.

Are there methods to find additional information about such failing?

Edit:

I am using Managed Compatibilty Mode option. Native code debugging option of c# application is enabled. Mixed debug type of other projects is turn on.

Comment: @Humam Helfawi, Debugger reaches breakpoints. But it fails during debugging method, which uses handlers

Comment: I've seen it, I don't know what causes it.  Mixed-mode debugging is rather a mixed blessing in general, the debugging engines in VS2013 and VS2015 especially are not very stable.  You'll have to punt this problem.  If you are 100% sure this is not something *really* nasty in your native code then just disable unmanaged debugging in your C# project to get ahead.  If you need pure native debugging because there is really something nasty going on then make your C++/CLI project the startup project and change its Debugging > Command setting to your C# exe.

Comment: @Hans Passant, My problem is that native code is not complete. Except other goals, c# application helps to add and test new features of native code, thus mixed debugging is essential for me. Debugger failing seems weird for me, because my application works fine.

Comment: Bad idea, isn't it?  "Not complete" invariably means "untested, buggy and likely to suffer from UB and crash in a nasty way".  Write your tests in C++ and only interop when it is stable.

Comment: As the message states, this generally occurs with incorrect COM marshalling or other forms of heap corruption.  If I run into this, I try debugging with native only and watching the exceptions that occur.  If you want the low level details of what causes it ... this message means that an unhandled exception occurred during an "out of band" event.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2005/09/13/out-of-band-events-and-mixed-mode-debugging/.  If the debugger were to try and stop here, it would deadlock so it has no choice but to continue the process and allow it to crash.